# How do I slide on my shield?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

How do I ride on my shield in Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild for the Nintendo Switch?

[image: Sliding on shield]

Comment: You do it like Legolas, with [style and panache](https://i.makeagif.com/media/2-15-2015/yJiPpE.gif).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This guide](http://www.gosunoob.com/zelda-breath-of-wild/how-to-surf-on-the-shield-zelda-botw/) explains how to slide on your shield pretty well:

> Let’s explain how to surf on the shield. To execute the shield surf, stand on any slope that you want to go down. Then, hold ZL so that Link performs the shield block. Then just press A (or jump and press A) and you’ll be on your way down.
>
> As we’ve said above, during your surf on your shield, you can do a 1080 spin by pressing Y (works as a Spin Attack) and you can apparently perform tricks by hitting X and tilting the left stick at the same time.

A word of warning, however, from the same guide:

> Surfing on the shield, any shield, damages it significantly. Try and avoid going down rocky terrain and stick to snow and/or grass. However, even that won’t save your shield for long. Be especially careful not to let the shield [break] while you’re mid-surf, since that will propel you forwards and deal damage or even send you careening down the mountain to your death.

Comment: Nothing like losing 10+ hearts while you roll down a mountain for a good 3-4 minutes.

Comment: Eh I once came out of shield surf and hit a moose which naturally headbutted me

Comment: Why would you shield surf anyways other than to save time?